# where to write and save the dockerfile?

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am a beginner in docker, my question can be considered somewhat obvious but where do I save and write the dockerfile?
example:

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

LABEL maintainer "Tobias Verbeke <tobias.verbeke@openanalytics.eu>"

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0

# system library dependency for the euler app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmpfr-dev

# basic shiny functionality
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# install dependencies of the euler app
RUN R -e "install.packages('Rmpfr', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/euler
COPY euler /root/euler

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/euler')"]
```

where specifically does this file have to be written? Where specifically does he have to be saved? what format does it have to be saved?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I follow is to include the Dockerfile in the root of the project directory.

I also store it in the same repo as the project.

Comment: do you save as .txt and save in a folder in your pc?

Comment: No I call it 'Dockerfile'